# Redirect my website joomla

Tags: php, url, redirect, joomla, geolocation

I want to redirect my website in differents languages when detect the country by (GeoIP), actually i have these urls and works well clicking on the flag images.

www.myweb.com/en 
 www.myweb.com/es 
 www.myweb.com/pt

But i dont know how to do it in joomla using the geoip.

I tried with .htacess and the answer of this question

[how to redirect domain according to country IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838344/how-to-redirect-domain-according-to-country-ip-address)

and i have the error 500

SOLUTION:

Joomla provides a browser settings in system language plugin, just setting the joomla with this works perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

This extension does the job: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/11173 Note that it's commercial. Your alternative would be download the GeoIP database (it's available for free), and then create a small plugin that does the redirection.

If you want, you can take a look at our post here: http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-block-a-whole-country-on-your-joomla-website on how to block a country. You will only need to slightly modify the code to make it so that it redirects to another page for a certain country.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

- Create a [system plugin for Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897522/execute-php-script-inside-joomla-cms-once-geo-based-redirection)
- PHP functions available for [checking visitors country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip) use that identify the location.

  redirect according to that.

Hope it helps..